# Why do I get undefined method `default_scoped?'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Starting from the object contract I would like to get all contract which get a product related to object `obseque`

So I created a scope :

**produit.rb**

```
def self.named_scope_obseque_method
 where(:code_reference => Produit::PRODUIT_REF_OB)
end

scope(:obseque, proc { named_scope_obseque_method })
```

**contrat.rb**

```
scope :obseques, -> {joins(:produit).merge(produit_id: Produit.obseque.map(&:id))}
```

And calling `Contrat.obseques` should return all contract which has a `product` related to `obseque`

But I get :

> > NoMethodError: undefined method `default_scoped?' for {:produit_id=>[3]}:Hash
> >     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/relation/spawn_methods.rb:11:in`merge'

---

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "produits", :force => true do |t|
    t.string "initiales",      :limit => 2
    t.string "code_reference", :limit => 100
  end

  create_table "obseques", :force => true do |t|
    t.string  "nom"
    t.integer "produit_id"
  end

  create_table "contrats", :force => true do |t|
    ...
    t.integer  "produit_id"
    ...
  end
```

**Produit.rb**

```
 has_one :obseque, :class_name => "Obseque", :foreign_key => "produit_id"
 has_many :contrats, :class_name => "Contrat", :foreign_key => "produit_id"
```

**contrat.rb**

```
  belongs_to :produit, :class_name => "Produit", :foreign_key => "produit_id"
```

**obseque.rb**

```
  belongs_to :produit, :class_name => "Produit", :foreign_key => "produit_id"
```

Comment: @sawa Yes sorry, I didn't set the title properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
scope :obseques, -> {
  joins(:produit).
    merge(produit_id: Produit.obseque.map(&:id)) # ⇐ HERE
}
```

You are passing a hash parameter to `merge`. You should join the scopes instead:

```
scope :obseques, -> {
  joins(:produit).
    where(produit_id: Produit.obseque.map(&:id))
}
```